# Compile library such that GDB finds sources automatically

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, gdb

We are compiling a library with CMAKE under Linux which is then installed per default under `/opt/mylib` and its sources are placed in this folder as well.

When users try to debug with GDB the library sources are not found by GDB automatically.

**How can we compile the library that GDB finds sources without specifying anything?**

For example the C++ standard library works like that. I can debug an application and I do not have to tell GDB where to find the sources.

Note: This question is not about how to make GDB find the sources (I know how to do this) but how to adapt the `CMakeLists.txt` and the compile process that it is not necessary to manually specify the source directory in GDB.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but one solution might be to define a symbolic link on the target machine called `/path/to/my/sources` pointing at `/opt/mylib`

Comment: I'm confident that it *is* possible, because `rpmbuild` performs a similar trick to create debuginfo RPMs, which install not only debugging symbols but also sources, with the latter in a different location than where the binaries were built.  GDB correctly locates the sources provided that way.  I just don't know offhand how `rpmbuild` does that.

Comment: After investigating some, it appears that `rpmbuild` comes packaged with a program, `debugedit`, for modifying ELF debug info for the purpose.  This is an internal program, not installed in the path, and unlike many other RPM components, it's a binary, not a script.  If you want to figure out how it works, then I'm sure the source is available.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `debugedit` looks like a potential solution. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for the `-fdebug-prefix-map=old=new` GCC flag.

From the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html):

> When compiling files residing in directory old, record debugging information describing them as if the files resided in directory new instead. This can be used to replace a build-time path with an install-time path in the debug info. It can also be used to change an absolute path to a relative path by using . for new. This can give more reproducible builds, which are location independent, but may require an extra command to tell GDB where to find the source files. See also -ffile-prefix-map.

The "may require an extra command" part applies if you want to debug as-built binaries without installing them. Debugging installed binaries will just work (TM).